# Scotchbox - Can't connect to MySql server on 'localhost' (10061)

Tags: mysql, ssh, virtual-machine, laravel-5

I have a fresh install of laravel and scotchbox. I'm trying to connect to my database, but i alsays receive the error

> Can't connect to MySql server on 'localhost' (10061)

Here are my **connection settings:**
[image]

And here are my **SSH settings:**

[image: http://puu.sh/nQZYq/852bb602a9.png]

Some **additional info**:

- I did vagrant up and the VM is running.
- I also tried SSH port 22 with no results.
- Connecting to my Localhost database works without any problem.

Thanks in advance for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have same error "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)” and I used to restart the system and it used to work.  I was using vagrant (for Bahmni-system) inside virtualbox. I then added gui through vagrantfile.  I realised that whenever the error has raised , I could just check my centos gui and found that the centos would have come to sleeping mode and i could just log in. After that I could connect the mysql server via HeidiSQL.

So, reasons that I could suggest for the occurrence of the error can be :

1. Either the system or OS on the VM machine has moved to sleeping mode or some kind of timeout.
2. Or, the connection to mysql server has timed-out. Maybe need to start the mysql service again using the vagrant.